# Sidekiq slow on development machine only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load, background-process, sidekiq

I'm running sidekiq 5.2.2 on Rails 5.2.1 with the following settings in the sidekiq.yml file;

```
---
retries: 1
:concurrency: 25
staging:
  :concurrency: 25
production:
  :concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - critical
  - default
  - low
```

My worker adds accounts when a ledger is made so that I don't delay the frontend. When I create the ledger on the staging server or production sidekiq springs into action straight away. The load on these machines is very low (0.05). However when I run the same test on my development machine I get mixed results;

```
  | version | concurrency | Cold | 1st  |  2nd | 3rd  | Warm |
  |         |   (threads) |      | Run  |  Run | Run  | AVG  |
  |---------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------|
  |   5.1.3 |          25 | 0.01 | 0.25 | 3:34 | 0:38 | 1:32 |
  |   5.2.2 |          10 | 3:43 |      | 0:30 |      |      |
```

The load on my development box is 6 at it's lowest. There is a lot going on within this development machine. It has 16 CPU's so this load is not stressing the machine.

What is causing sidekiq to fluctuate starting workers so much on the development machine? Could it be load?

**Update**

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development_<%= ENV['USER'] %>
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PAIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

puma.rb settings

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Procfile: Starting sidekiq using foreman

```
rails:  bundle exec puma -p $RAILS_PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Comment: Can you give the what is the pool count in database.yml and what server you are using in your development, if Puma, what is the workers count and threads count in your Puma configuration, these details may help for better understanding

Comment: Also, show us how you're configuring Sidekiq/Redis (perhaps https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2986 is at play?)

Comment: I don't have any special redis configuration I just went with the defaults

Comment: One thing: looks like you don't have a large enough DB pool. You are sharing 5 connections between 10-25 threads.

Comment: Should I adjust the pool up to 25 or the concurrency down to 5?

Comment: I adjusted my database pool to 25 and it didn't make a difference

Comment: I also tried moving my concurrency down to 5 to match the 5 DB pools, no difference